# How to pick up adjectives or nouns out of a text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

For example like:

```
sentence = 'An old lady lives in a small red house. She has three cute cats, and their names match with their colors: White, Cinnamon, and Chocolate. They are poor but happy.'
```

So I hope to get 2 lists like these:

```
adj = ['old','small','red','cute','White','poor','happy']
noun = ['lady','house','cats','names','colors','Cinnamon','Chocolate']
```

I saw someone mentioned NLTK, but I haven't used the package so I would hope for some instructions.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called Part-Of-Speech(POS) Tagging, you could check:

- NLTK: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/part-speech-tagging-stop-words-using-nltk-python/
- Spacy: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#pos-tagging

If not enough, there are a lot of additional instructions for newbies out there if you google 'POS Tagging + python'.

btw, I would recommend `spacy` as it is more modern.